# Updating the contets of GridView using a custom adapter

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I want to update the contents of the GridView which shows some images using a custom adapter. Here is the code:

```
public class SudokuAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    List<Integer> numbers;
    private Context context;
    public SudokuAdapter(Context context,List<Integer> numbers)
    {
    this.numbers=numbers;
    this.context=context;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numbers.size();
}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return numbers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void updateList(List <Integer> numbers)
{
    this.numbers=numbers;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // String drawableName = "R.drawable.sudo_1";
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    //int resId=context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sudo_1);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    return imageView;

}
}
```

I am making a calling updateList() but the app is going back to the previous activity. I suspect there is a problem in my getView(). Can anyone figure out what's wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by *but the app is going back to the previous activity*?

Comment: The GridView above is present in GameActivity. When I call updateList() from GameActivity., the screen shows the layout of MainActivity, which is the activity from which I called GameActivity.

Comment: what are you calling after you call updateList? Would you mind sharing it with us ?

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        nums.add(position + 1);
                        adapter.updateList(nums);
                    }